# XPath is not working even when directly copied from Chrome inspect

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, servicenow

I have been trying to automate my work and we use service-now for our requests. However, for the the life of me I can not get Selenium to run properly on the service-now website. It works on the login page before entering, but no matter what form of locater or x path I use it will not work. The website is dynamic so I am pretty sure xpath is needed.

I have tried directly from Google Chrome inspect as well as other xpath possibilities:

```
//*[@id="row_sc_request.sc_task.request_65091fb5db8163c4bc8f18df4b961921"]/td[3]/a

xpath=//a[starts-with(text(),'Open record: SCTA')]

xpath=//a[class="linked formlink" and starts-with(@aria-label='Open record: SCTA')]
```

This is the element copied from chrome

```html
<a class="linked formlink" aria-label="Open record: SCTASK0067185" href="sc\\\_task.do?sys\\\_id=65091fb5db8163c4bc8f18df4b961921\\\&amp;sysparm\\\_record\\\_target=sc\\\_task\\\&amp;sysparm\\\_record\\\_row=1\\\&amp;sysparm\\\_record\\\_rows=1\\\&amp;sysparm\\\_record\\\_list=request%3D9509dbb5db8163c4bc8f18df4b96199f%5EORDERBYDESCnumber">SCTASK0067185</a>
```

Can someone please review my code? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: have you checked that if an element is in iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your answers. It turns out all I needed to do was switch the IFrame.
I am fairly new to this so I had no idea.

In my situatuion, I had to write:

```
"browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_name('gsft_main'))"
```

where gsft_main is the name of the frame.

After doing this, then I was able to use:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='linked formlink' and starts-with(@aria-label, 'Open record: SCTA' )]")
```

and it worked out.

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest going with absolute XPath, I guess below note can help

Note:- if you copy XPath from Firefox it will mostly give you absolute XPath whereas chrome on another side will give relative

or the other way is to make an XPath using another stable element in the DOM tree

I hope this workout for yours. if you can share a link or inspect element snapshot showing Full DOM I can help you even better. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in the second xpath, this one - `xpath=//a[class="linked formlink" and starts-with(aria-label='SCTA')]`. 
In xpath the attributes must be prefixed with the "@" char; and `starts-with()` takes two arguments, not a boolean. So it must be:

```
xpath=//a[@class="linked formlink" and starts-with(@aria-label, "SCTA" )]
```

I don't know for sure will that make it match (it should, based on the sample), but will get you closer.

Comment: Thank you, that is for sure a step in the righ direction. But it is still not working. I have been using Selenium IDE to test it and no luck.

Comment: Test the xpath in the browser itself - open the dev tools, and in the console use the method `$x()` with your value; e.g. `$x('//a[@class="linked formlink" and starts-with(@aria-label, "SCTA" )]')`. This is times faster than starting a case in any framework, selenium IDE including.

Comment: That is so much faster thank you! It shows up in the browser console and returns that it is a link. However it still does not properly show up when requesting to click it. It now states "The result is not a node set, and therefore can not be converted to desired type."

Comment: What python method do you use to get the element?

Comment: There are limitation of selenium IDE to handle such dynamic links, that is why it;s not working instead use selenium web driver and write a dynamic code to handle this.

Comment: There's a possibility that there are multiple elements matching with this XPATH and its not clicking because of that.. Can you the number of elements with Chrome inspection?

Answer (score 0):

A solution might be to switch from an absolute xpath (the one that you find in the browser's developer tools: Copy->Copy XPath) to a relative one. For that you can install an extension like [SelectorsHub](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selectorshub/ndgimibanhlabgdgjcpbbndiehljcpfh/related) and look for 'Rel XPath'

In one particular example I discovered that the absolute xpath simply did not work.